# Laravel wkhtml2pdf - Syntax error unexpected '['

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using the wkhtml2pdf package with Laravel 4.

http://packalyst.com/packages/package/nitmedia/wkhtml2pdf

I have it installed and configured correctly for my machine (ubuntu server 12.04 running on a amd64 processor). My test action looks like this:

```
<?php
class PDFController extends BaseController
{
public function handleConvert() {

    return PDF::html('Test.view');
}
```

}
?>

The error I receive when running this action is this:
http://puu.sh/6hreq.png

I have debugging turned on in the package, but I'm not getting the standard debugging error but a symphony error. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: Array derreferencing is only supported in PHP 5.4+. What version are you using?

Comment: I'm using PHP Version 5.4.10, does that version include array derreferencing? Sorry I'm not familiar with what that feature is.

Comment: Ignore my last comment, our production server's version is PHP 5.3.* let me try updating it!

Comment: That was the solution! Thank you @enclanrs! For anyone else stuck on this using ubuntu server 12.04 use this guide to upgrade to 5.4

http://serverfault.com/questions/420286/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-6-in-ubuntu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@enclars provided the solution. If you encounter this error, upgrade your PHP version to 5.4.1+

I did it on my ubuntu server by following this guide:  https://serverfault.com/questions/420286/how-do-i-upgrade-from-php-5-3-to-php-5-4-6-in-ubuntu